# Generate html mail in bash to use with mail command

Tags: html, bash, email

I created a simple script in which a certain information is send via mail like this:

`printf "Dear $i, please enable 2fa on $site.\n\n Your inital code: \n $code \n\n\n For detailed instructions visit:\n https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/user_manual/en/user_2fa.html \n\n You must complete the above steps from instructions, otherwise you will not be able to log into your account a second time!\n\n Regards - Your Site Administrator from $site" | mail -s "Urgent notice from $site" $email -r $mail_from`

I would rather send this mail as html with predefined variables. Tried to create a simple html file, saved it locally an read it in the script via cat:

`` template=`cat ./mail_template ``

Contents of mail_template is:

```
Dear $i,

please enable 2fa on $site. This is very important to protect your identity.

Your inital code for logging in to your account the next time: 

$code

For detailed instructions please visit:
https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/user_manual/en/user_2fa.html

You must complete the above steps from instructions, otherwise you will not be able to log into your account a second time!

In short you need to do the following steps:

1.) Log in to your account on $site using above code
2.) Enable 2FA as shown in the instruction ( link above )
3.) Enable security tokens as shown in instructions ( link above )

<bold>Attention!!!</bold>
Don't save security tokens to your Nextcloud File Storage. Put them in another safe( preferably encrypted ) place, or print them out and store them in a vault.


Regards - Your Site Administrator from $site
```

I included the html and body tags in mail_template. Can't show them here because it screws up the formatting.

Then the new mail statement is this:

`printf "$template" | mail -a 'Content-Type: text/html'  -s "Urgent notice from $site" $email -r $mail_from`

Unfortunately this is not working. The variables from the mail_template are written as normal strings, also the html tags are not recognized.

Any any how to do this the correct way? Thanks.

cheers, toddehb

Comment: A couple remarks: An HTML-only message is likely to encounter deliverability issues (tagged spam), especially if it contains keywords such as security, password, login… The shell is really not a good environment to produce mail other than very simple plaintext messages. Python or Perl would be a way more appropriate choice for sending MIME compliant Mixed-content `text/plain` and `text/html` messages. Or just to fill up a message template for simple plain/text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `envsubst` for current template like this:

```
i=John
site=foo.com
code=123456
    
template=$(i="$i" site="$site" code="$code" envsubst < ./mail_template)
echo "$template"
Dear John,

please enable 2fa on foo.com. This is very important to protect your identity.

Your inital code for logging in to your account the next time: 

123456

For detailed instructions please visit:
...
```

Or change template to make it printfriendly like this:

```
template=$(cat ./mail_template)
echo "$template"
Dear %s,

please enable 2fa on %s. This is very important to protect your identity.

Your inital code for logging in to your account the next time: 

%s

For detailed instructions please visit:
...
```

then use it with `printf` like this:

```
printf "$template" "$i" "$site" "$code" | ...
```

Another way is to use `sed`, change template like this:

```
Dear _name_,

please enable 2fa on _site_. This is very important to protect your identity.

Your inital code for logging in to your account the next time: 

_code_

For detailed instructions please visit:
...
```

and use `sed` to paste actual data instead of *name*, *site* and *code*:

```
template=$(sed "s/_name_/$i/;s/_site_/$site/;s/_code_/$code/" ./mail_template)
```